# how export get-vm info to csv file in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, vmware-esx

How can I export this output to csv file ?

I have this output from below get-vm command:

`Get-VM  | Select Name, PowerState, GuestId, @{N="VM Config File";E={$_.extensiondata.config.files.vmpathname}}`

```
Name           : test-vm
PowerState     : PoweredOff
GuestId        : rhel7_64Guest
VM Config File : [DS_001] test-vm/test-vm.vmx

Name           : test-vm2
PowerState     : PoweredOn
GuestId        : sles12_64Guest
VM Config File : [DS_002] test-vm2/test-vm2.vmx
```

I would like to add also VLAN info
`get-vm | Get-NetworkAdapter |Select NetworkName`

Final Output should be this:

```
NAME, POWERSTATE, GuestiD, VM Config File, NetworkName
test-vm, PoweredOff,rhel7_64Guest, [DS_001] test-vm/test-vm.vmx, VLAN-100
test-vm2, PoweredOn,sles12_64Guest, [DS_002] test-vm2/test-vm2.vmx, VLAN-200
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to get all the VMware system results into one csv file.

> **This essentially...**
>
> 1. Exports the VM data **excluding the network name** into a `csv1.csv` file.
> 2. Exports the VM data **containing the network name** into a `csv2.csv` file.
> 3. Uses `Write-Output` to explicitly define the header columns into a `Merged.csv` file.
> 4. Uses `Import-Csv` against the `csv1.csv` file and loops that over a `For-EachObject`.
> 5. Within the `For-EachObject` loop it:
>
>    - defines a `$name` variable with the value of `$_.Name` (from `csv1`)
>    - defines an `$oName` variable for the `NetworkName` (from `csv2`) using `Import-Csv` against the `csv2.csv` where its `Name` value is
>      the same as the current iterated `Name` [`$name`] in `csv1`
>    - uses `Write-Output` to specify all the properties and variables in order matching the column headers
>
>      - uses [PowerShell subexpression operators](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html) enclosing them
>        in `$()` and separates each by a comma
>
>        - encloses the entire group of subexpression operators with double quotes then pipes that over to  `Out-File` using the `-Append` parameter and points to the
>          the final `Merged.csv` file for the preferred output.

### PowerShell

```
Get-VM  | 
Select Name, PowerState, GuestId, 
    @{N="VM Config File";E={$_.extensiondata.config.files.vmpathname}} |
        Export-Csv "C:\Temp\csv1.csv" -NoTypeInformation;

Get-VM | Get-NetworkAdapter | Select @{n="Name";e={$_.Parent}}, 
     NetworkName | Export-Csv "C:\Temp\csv2.csv" -NoTypeInformation;

Write-Output 'Name, Powerstate, GuestId, VM Config File, NetworkName' | Out-File "C:\Temp\Merged.csv";
Import-Csv "C:\Temp\csv1.csv" | % {
    $name = $_.Name;
    $oName = (Import-Csv C:\Temp\csv2.csv | ? {$_.Name -eq $name} | Select NetworkName).NetworkName;
    Write-Output "$($_.Name), $($_.PowerState), $($_.GuestId), $($_.'VM Config File'), $($oName)" | Out-File "C:\Temp\Merged.csv" -Append;
    };
```

---

## Supporting Resources

- [Export-Csv](https://ss64.com/ps/export-csv.html)

  > `-NoTypeInformation`
  >
  > Remove the #TYPE information header from the output.    This
  > parameter became the default in PowerShell 6.0 and is included for
  > backwards compatibility.
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [Where-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/where-object.html)

  > The '`?`' symbol and Where are both aliases for Where-Object. If you
  > explicitly want to run the Where-Object command, run Where-object or
  > '`?`'
- [PowerShell Operators $( ) @( ) :: &](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html)

  > `$( )` Subexpression operator.
  >
  > While a simple `( )` grouping expression means 'execute this part
  > first', a subexpression `$( )` means '**execute this first and then treat
  > the result like a variable**'.
- [Out-File](https://ss64.com/ps/out-file.html)

  > `-append`
  >
  > Add the output to the end of an existing file, instead of replacing the file contents.
  > You need to ensure the `-encoding` matches any existing content in the target file